# swfobject getFlashPlayerVersion does not work in IE

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, swfobject

swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion doesn't work in IE, any alternatives?

Comment: i think you need to be a bit more specific than "doesn't work" to get any good answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your flash version is 10.0.12 then the following code allows you to retrieve the version nr:

```
var playerVersion = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion(); // returns a JavaScript object
var majorVersionNr = playerVersion.major; //returns the major nr: 10
var minorVersionNr = playerVersion.minor; //returns the minor nr: 0
var releaseVersionNr = playerVersion.release; //returns the version nr: 12
```

Comment: the problem im having is that in IE when i try the following: playerVersion.major == "0" and if i dont have Flash installed IE doesnt not recognise the command

Comment: so playerVersion == null? Doesn't that say enough then?

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought: try `swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion(versionStr)` instead.

Comment: good idea, it asks for a minimum flash version and returns a boolean if the minimum is met...